# Select top-2 products in each of the top-5 groups as of revenue

Tags: postgresql, limit, alias, window-functions, lateral

I have a table called **bills** with the following columns: **id**, **product** – product id, **product_group** – product_group_id, **Revenue** – revenue in some currency

I would like to get top-2 products from top-5 product groups as of their revenue. Any help is appreciated.

This is i have gone so far:

```
select t.sum_product_group,
    t.sum_product
from (
    select bills.product_group,
        bills.product,
        bills.revenue,
        sum(bills.revenue) over (partition by bills.product_group) as sum_product_group,
        sum(bills.revenue) over (partition by bills.product) as sum_product,
    from bills
    ) as t
order by t.sum_product_group desc,
    t.sum_product desc limit 2
```

Comment: Do you want a global top-5 product, which is also in the top-7 group, or top-5 products **per** the top-7 groups? Also, how do you want to handle ties? (I.e. when multiple products/groups have the same `sum(revenue)`.) -- Also, in your first sentence, the limits are the exact opposite: please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. That is right I made a mistake in the description. I would like to get top-7 products out of top-5 product groups as of their sum revenue (not top 7 products for each top product group). If there are ties we can use minimum id in order to obtain a limited selection of top-5 product groups and top-7 products within those 5 product groups.

Comment: I have changed the condition of my task. Now i would like to get top-2 products in each of the top-5 product groups as of their revenue. I have found this information but can not integrate it my solution: http://charlesnagy.info/it/postgresql/group-by-limit-per-group-in-postgresql

Comment: Can you post some example data and the output you expect?

Comment: Here is a link to initial dataset https://www.dropbox.com/s/avvw9u215fdm84u/1.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Blue columns - initial column. Green - computed columns (I suppose using window functions etc.)

Comment: And here is a link to desired output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/avvw9u215fdm84u/1.jpg?dl=0